# How to calculate p-value comparing bootstrap-based predicted probabilities and observed probabilities

Tags: r, permutation, p-value, statistics-bootstrap, hypothesis-test

Given the sample data `dat` below, I would appreciate any help to:

(1) check whether my approach below following boot's [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf) to calculate bootstrap-based predictions from logistic regression is correct and help correct if there is any mistake in my approach.

(2) calculate
    bootstrap-based p-values comparing the observed probability and the predicted probability.

**#my sample data:**

```
ldose <- rep(0:5, 2)
numdead <- c(1, 4, 9, 13, 18, 20, 0, 2, 6, 10, 12, 16)
sex <- factor(rep(c("M", "F"), c(6, 6)))
SF <- cbind(numdead, numalive = 20-numdead)
dat<-data.frame(ldose, numdead, sex, SF)
tibble::rowid_to_column(dat, "indices")

new.data <- data.frame(ldose = 20, sex = "F")
```

**#doing bootstrap:**

```
#Here I would appreciate any correction if something is not correct in my approach

temp.out<-function(dat, indices, new.data) {
     d<-dat[indices, ] 
     fit1<- glm(SF ~ sex*ldose, family = binomial (link = logit), data = d)  
     return(predict(fit1, new.data, type="response"))
}

results <- boot::boot(dat, temp.out, 1000, sim = "permutation")

boot::boot.ci(results, conf = 0.95, type = "all") #this fails

     Error in model.frame.default(formula = SF ~ sex * ldose, data = d, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
      variable lengths differ (found for 'sex')

boot::boot.ci(results, conf = c(0.90, 0.95), type = c("perc")) #this works
```

**#calculating bootstrap-based p-value comparing the observed probability(e.g., 0.45) and the predicted probabilities (based on the bootstrap algorithm):**

```
#Here I would appreciate any help to calculate the p-value
```

Thanks in advance for any help. If there is anything that is not clear, please kindly let me know.

Comment: What's your definition of this p-value that you want to find?

Comment: H0: predicted probabilities =observed probabilities, H1: predicted probabilities != observed probabilities. Example of observed probability: 0.45

Comment: @JuliusVainora, any thoughts?

Comment: I will delete the question and repost after editing. Probably the question is not clear enough.

Comment: Given your comment I think everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks, @JuliusVainora. Any thoughts about questions (1) and (2)?

Comment: For (1): you need `boot::boot(dat, temp.out, 1000, sim = "permutation", new.data = new.data)` as otherwise `new.data` doesn't get passed.

Comment: Great, @JuliusVainora. That solved one issue I was facing.